# Router supports WPS but had no WPS button?

Tags: wireless-networking, mikrotik-routeros, wps

I'm trying to connect my HP LaserJet 100 color MFP M175 PCL6 via WPS to my router/modem MikroTik RB951G-2HnD, but there's no button like on my old router from my phone provider. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your router via winbox or via browser go to the terminal and run this to simulate the wps press.

Assuming your WLAN interface is called **wlan1** otherwise just adjust to your wlan interface name

```
/interface wireless wps-push-button wlan1
```

**Note**: I dont have WPS turned on.

[image]